# English or Telugu translations of works of Bodhendra Saraswathi

Tags: advaita, translation-request

Bodhendra Saraswathi was a Jivan Mukta and worked as 58th Acharya of Sri Kanchi kamakoti Peetam. You can read about him from the [Kamakoti website](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/June%202010%20-vadavambalam.html).

> Sri Atma Bodhendra Saraswathi Swamiji attained mukti on the banks of
> the river South Pinakini, known in Tamil as Then Pennai on Krishna
> Ashtami in the month of Tula of the cyclic year Eswara (1638 AD). The
> Adhistanam of Sri Atma Bodhendra Saraswathi Swamiji is located at the
> place, now known as Vadavambalam, near Panrutti. The Adhistanam was
> discovered by the directions of His Holiness Pujyasri Mahaswamiji
> (details of which are painted on the walls of the adhistanam) and was
> consecrated on 17 January 1927. Jeernodharana Ashtabandana
> Kumbabhishekam was performed on 17 January 1981.

I came across some of [his works in archive](https://archive.org/search.php?query=subject%3A%22Bodhendra%20Saraswati%22)

1. Bhagavan Nama Kaumudi
2. Naamaamruta Rasaayanam
3. Yoga Vasista commentary

and he wrote bhasya on the Sri Rudram.

Most of the available ones I can see are in Hindi.

Are there any English or Telugu translations of the works of Bodhendra Saraswathi?

Answer (score 2):

I guess Sri Bodhendral Mutt at Kumbakonam, the place where His Holiness attained Siddhi would publish his works. This is their website:
**[www.sribodhendralmutt.org/book-shop](http://www.sribodhendralmutt.org/book-shop)**

These are his works with English translation which I could find online. Out of his 40 works barely 2 are available online:

https://philpapers.org/rec/VEDSOT

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=hOlPngEACAAJ&printsec=front_cover&redir_esc=y

https://www.exoticindia.com/book/details/sri-bhagavan-namamrutha-rasodayam-nal037/

Comment: I'm contacting them and will try to post once they conform.

Comment: Telugu is unavailable. I didn't ask for English.